# Is there a definitive guide for setting up Mamp Pro so local network users can view/edit sites?

Tags: installation, mamp, lan

I've been researching how to setup a LAN Mamp Pro server so local users can edit/view sites - but there seems to be a lot of confusion (at least I'm confused based on why I've read).

Specific questions:

**Running Apache/Mysql as www/mysql:** When I switch the users to www/mysql I see permissions issues and can't login to my CMS from the machine running Mamp Pro. What's the best way of fixing this or running Mamp Pro - taking into consideration permissions when using pushing to DEV and LIVE servers using Git and Github.

**Ports:** What is more secure, running Mamp Pro using ports 8888/8889 or the defaults of 80/3306? And is the only difference adding/not adding port numbers when viewing sites?

**Access to sites by users on the same LAN:** What are the steps for getting this working - the firewall on the MAMP Pro machine is currently off to test the basic setup but no one on our local network can connect to the sites - have tried **192.168.0.1:8888** & **virtualhostname:8888**

Sorry if this is easy but for a paid product, Mamp Pro help and support is pretty scarce and I suspect this stuff is easy if you know how to setup a linux server - but if you don't know how to do this, it's why you purchase MAMP Pro right?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: OK, so have finally seen the permissions button in Mamp Pro and have changed the users to www/mysql and updated the permissions on the site directory - so point one above is now not an issue and can login to the CMS fine now.

Comment: I also have "allow local access only" turned on in the MySQL settings.  My understanding is that this only affects programs trying to access the database that are not installed locally - and because people on the LAN will only interact with MySQL via the CMS using a browser, I assume this is the correct setting in this instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I did:

**Setup:**

- I'm developing the site on my local computer
- Mamp Pro is running on my local computer
- I would like other people on the local network to login to the CMS on my computer and update the CMS

**Server settings:**

- Use the default ports `80/3306` (just don't have web sharing turned on in OSX prefs) - I'm sure you could use the MAMP ports if you want
- Run `Apache/MySQL` server as users `www/mysql`

**Virtual host settings:**

- Give your server a name
- Leave local name resolution on
- Add the IP address of the computer Mamp Pro is running on e.g. `192.167.1.1`
- Add a port number (this will be the unique way of identifying sites on the LAN - see below for more) I just used port `8888`
- If you had a site setup prior to switching the Apache/MySQL users, click the "Permissions" button under the disk location and set owner to www and the group to admin so your local admin account has access - click "Set"
- If the above step doesn't work properly, you'll now need to CMD + I the website directory and ensure your local machine admin has rights to read and write to the directory - be sure to click the cog and select "Apply to enclosed items" so the rights get applied to the directories inside
- Start the virtual host

**Accessing the site from another machine on the same LAN:**

- Enter the IP address of the Mamp Pro machine followed by the port number you entered
- e.g. `http://192.168.1.1:8888/`
- If you have multiple sites, just enter a different port number in the setup

This works for me and staff can now edit the CMS and view the site but it seems a bit 'hacky' to me using a different port for each site as the way to differentiate sites in development.

Please sing out if there's abetter way - this is just how I got it working.

Answer (score 3):

I have numerous sites set up with MAMP Pro.

To access a specific site, try shuffling it to the **top of the list of sites in MAMP Pro**, and then access using the IP address and port (as described above),

```
e.g. http://192.168.1.1:8888/
```

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

I've met the problem "PHP Warning:  ...: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Samples/ch17/upload_01.php on line 17". And your suggesting "Virtual host settings" also works for that! Thank you~~

Answer (score 0):

"Access to sites by users on the same LAN..."

A more general solution would be to run a proxy server using Squid. SquidMan (http://squidman.net/squidman/) is a nice graphic front-end for setting Squid up, but to do what you want, you shouldn't need to do more than set your local network up under "Clients" and identify the machine it's running on as a proxy in your web server...

Comment: The SquidMan solution is beautiful, but it doesn't seem to work with HTTPS connections for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Others here may have their DHCP setup beginning 192.168... but my Comcast setup actually defaulted to 10.0.0... which is what was causing me so much grief because MAMP doesn't like zeros in the host IP address. You need to go into your router and change the default gateway to something else. Then you will be able to access each of your hosted sites by specifying a port number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your mamp websites across lan with there respective domain names not the ip address or ports, you can do this by simply editing the hosts file on your mac.

Or use a tool like https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40003/hosts

Point all your domains to the IP of the MAMP host computer, and put the mamp web service on port 80.

use www.domain.dev or similar for the domain names.