# Accessing multiple MAMP Pro sites over LAN?

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, lan

I develop my web sites on Mac 10.8.3 using MAMP Pro 2.1.1.

I create a host for each project.  Works perfectly on my local machine.  However, now I need to make it accessible to my iPad and other devices over our LAN.

I have searched and Googled, and attempted to implement the steps [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092154/is-there-a-definitive-guide-for-setting-up-mamp-pro-so-local-network-users-can-v) to no avail.

The iPad can access the main "localhost" on MAMP by just entering the IP address of the Mac into Mobile Safari. So it can see MAMP.

The issue is accessing one of the other virtual hosts. For example, I create a virtual host "myhost" set the IP to the IP of the Mac and the port to 8050.

But the iPad will not load it.  I have tried setting permissions for the site to everyone read/write.  I have tried running as www/mysql and as myself (the default).

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to your question. Have you figured anything out since posting this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit "hosts" file on your device or try to use "localhost" for all websites and separate them by apache ports if that's possible.